# Does electrical wire expand when electricity is flowing?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electricity, everyday-life

My home was recently re wired and after seeing the state of the old wiring I was left wondering why I had to replace the wiring after only 12 years. I know some people will say that I've been had off by the builder/spark, but the man in question is a very good and old friend and he was left puzzled at the condition of the wiring and I asked him the question I asked here, and he didn't know.

Comment: I'm pretty certain it will be the insulation that has deteriorated, not the copper wire. Copper is pretty stable in normal environments.

Comment: So, what was the "state of the old wiring"  that required replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Wires will expand a little bit because they are slightly resistive, so they heat up a little when current flows. Because copper has a positive coefficient of thermal expansion, it will expand with the heat. But in context, this would be a small effect given that your home wires are designed to heat up very little. Moreover, the wire insulation is typically made with a somewhat flexible material which could easily accommodate this small thermal expansion (and would itself expand), so it’s unlikely to have any relevance to the condition of your home wiring.

Comment: That "small effect" can be compounded over the decades—especially in the case where a wire splice or other connection was poor quality to begin with. The poor quality connection has higher resistance, gets hotter, expands more, becomes even less secure as a result. A poor connection in a circuit serving a high powered appliance eventually can get hot enough to start a fire. Especially true if the connection is not inside a fire-resistant enclosure. This became a big problem in the U.S.A. in the 1970s when aluminum wires were allowed to be connected to brass terminals.

Comment: @SolomonSlow good point.

Comment: My house was built in 1965. I have had no problems with the copper wires (which are enclosed in metal pipes).